# Get a #text element found in a span with importxml and Gsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the value of a #text (number of likes) inside a span from [this URL](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX67YC0MmS612) via importXML in Google Spreadsheet using XPath.

I tried so many ways but it doesn't work...

Any ideas ?

```html
<div class="RANLXG3qKB61Bh33I0r2 NO_VO3MRVl9z3z56d8Lg"><a draggable="false" class="Czg_RoYmXG0FPTHG9Kdb" href="/user/spotify">Spotify</a></div>
<span class="RANLXG3qKB61Bh33I0r2 Hi9FqPX1LNRRPf31tfA8" as="span">150 815&nbsp;likes</span>
```

Spotify

Answer (score 0):

Generic XPath to match your span tag is:

//span[contains(text(), 'like')]

This is a match for the sample url provided. The same "page" with, for example, another artist selected changes the html and can result in no match or several matches.

This example was checked against geckodriver